# How to put a button in a position of my will ? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

```
   new RaisedButton(
            splashColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
            color: Colors.Brown[200],
            onPressed: () {  },
            child: new Text(
              "Login",
              style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0 ,color: Colors.white),
```

This  is  the  code  of the button  i want to  style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Stack Widget then u are good to go

```
     Stack(
      children:[
             Postioned(
                     ...define here your widget Poition.
                  child:Text("my text")
                  )]
               )
```